# How to check crypt(3) sha512 password?

Tags: node.js, crypt

Given a password hash like,

```
$6$rounds=500000$RzOKKJIKZ18arhBR$E2JyKkCOZZXva89rAzvQOZxL1rZ.1wt9uC4yEVr0YkZkTbpi1bd7QBexgpbbc5qI4NvntJQAlrYSPg2bSvVr5/
```

And a plain-text password, how can I verify the password matches the hash in Node.js?

I've tried three different libs so far, and none of them support `$6$`. The official crypto lib seems to support sha512, but the [createHash](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm) method doesn't take a salt like that.

I'm using Node 6.2. The passwords were created using PHP's [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function which I believe is just a wrapper around the [C library function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)).

Comment: From [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php): *CRYPT_SHA512 - SHA-512 hash with a sixteen character salt prefixed with **$6$**. If the salt string starts with 'rounds=<N>$', the numeric value of N is used to indicate how many times the hashing loop should be executed, much like the cost parameter on Blowfish. The default number of rounds is 5000, there is a minimum of 1000 and a maximum of 999,999,999. Any selection of N outside this range will be truncated to the nearest limit.*

Comment: @zaph Right...I read all that. And I tried splitting the hash string apart and running it through various crypto functions, but I wasn't able to reproduce the exact same hash, ergo I can't validate my passwords. I'm not sure what key-strengthening method PHP uses...is it pbkdf2, or just repeated hashing or something else?

Comment: This is the problem with using algorithms that are mot fully defined. Best get the code and figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[crypt3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypt3) is able to [check](https://github.com/sendanor/node-crypt3#example-password-check) such passwords by calling the native C lib.